# How to escape numbers between group identifiers

Tags: rename

I'm using the utility **rename** to rename multiple files and I can't figure out how should I escape numbers between group identifiers. It must be elementary, but I've never faced the situation and my intuition doesn't help me to find the right escaping characters.

I want to replace any number in file name with `23`. I've tried the following:

```
rename -n 's/(.*)([0-9]{2})(.*)/$1"23"$3/' *

$ rename -n 's/(.*)([0-9]{2})(.*)/$1"23"$3/' *
rename(Request22Message.json, Request"23"Message.json)
rename(Response22ExpectedMessage.json, Response"23"ExpectedMessage.json)
rename(Response22Message.json, Response"23"Message.json)
```

Maybe dots are considered as concatenation characters in this case:

```
$ rename -n 's/(.*)([0-9]{2})(.*)/$1.23.$3/' *
rename(Request22Message.json, Request.23.Message.json)
rename(Response22ExpectedMessage.json, Response.23.ExpectedMessage.json)
rename(Response22Message.json, Response.23.Message.json)
```

No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really a matter of escaping the numbers - it's a matter of disambiguating from `$123` as a reference to capture group `123`. This case is covered tangentially in the `perlre` documentation under [Warning on \1 Instead of $1](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Warning-on-%5C1-Instead-of-$1)

> if you try to do
>
> ```
> s/(\d+)/\1000/;
> ```
>
> You can't disambiguate that by saying `\{1}000`, whereas you can fix it
> with `${1}000`.

So, for example

```
rename -n 's/(.*)([0-9]{2})(.*)/${1}23$3/' *.json
```

or (for symmetry)

```
rename -n 's/(.*)([0-9]{2})(.*)/${1}23${3}/' *.json
```

You *can* use the string concatenation operator `.` but that requires addition of the execution flag:

```
rename -n 's/(.*)([0-9]{2})(.*)/$1."23".$3/e' *.json
```

Comment: Or maybe `$1 . "23" . $1` to explicitly give a string and avoid surprises if the number is `023` instead. With a string `$1."23".$1`, works too, if you want to golf it.

Comment: @ilkkachu thanks both good points - edited accordingly

Comment: Ah ok. The braces are the key. The constructs `$(a)` or `${a}` are often used to get the value of a variable...